# Copy and rename file with modification date

Tags: powershell, cmd

I am doing a backup of a daily file from a shared route. Since this file is updated daily with the same name, I rename it on my backup adding the date of modification.
This is a very simple task in PowerShell. I made this, to do what I need but only for files with no date (YYYYMMDD):

```
xcopy /D/Y "\\serv123\sample\files.csv" "D:\Data\B_up\"
Get-ChildItem  | ForEach-Object {
   if (!($_.Name.Contains("20"))) { $_ | Rename-Item -NewName ("file"+$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd")+$_.Extension)}}
```

BUT as far as I know, I need to do a .exe file to make this executable with 2-clicks, to achieve that is required an extension but I don't have administrator user to install stuff on the computer.
So my question is, can I do that with CMD?

I suppose is something like: rem [Exact file name] [OldName]{something to give me the modification date with YYYYMMdd format}.csv

Comment: If it's about to start a Powershell script on double click you can create a short cut to something like this: `powershell.exe -ep bypass -file "path to your script"`

Comment: In what directory is `Get-ChildItem` reading?

Comment: @lit forgot to mention a cd